# How to upload npm 3-rd party package to intranet nexus server

Tags: reactjs, jenkins, npm, repository, nexus

How can I upload my react-app 3rd party packages to nexus in intranet?

env detail.

1.linux pc (server)

- installed nexus, and will use private repo.
- also will use my react app deploy with jenkins
- It use only intranet with my local pc

2.my local pc

- developed react app. there are npm third party package.
- can use internet.

problem.

I have to move 3rd party npm packages(like react, react-redux, material-ui ....) to nexus. because of deploy with jenkins.
 But i have no idea. How Can I move my local pc 3rd party packages to nexus all in one?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have created a repository of *npm (hosted)* type and this is where you publish your app. Create another repository, but this time *npm (proxy)* and point it to your repository of choice (*npmjs* or *yarnpkg*). You can also combine the two repositories using *npm (group)* repository, but remember you have to publish directly to the *npm (hosted)* repository. Once you've got this setup ready, remove all *node_modules* from your local PC and rebuild your app causing every package you will download end up in that proxy repository.